# Hibernate findByExample with non-primitive members

Tags: hibernate, orm

I have two entities...

File and User

File has a @ManyToOne Reference to User with the following annotation on the member:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private User user
```

I'm trying to find all the files for a user by using the "findByExample" method.

I've created an instance of File and an instance of User (with the username set). I've added the instance of User to the File instance and passed it to "findByExample" like this:

```
Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(File.class);
Example ex = Example.create(exampleInstance);
crit.add(ex);
return crit.list();
```

Unfortunately "list()" returns all the files in my db, not just the ones for the specified user. I inspected the generated SQL and I see that it's not inspecting the User object for any values, just joining the tables and doing a "where (1=1)".

Is it possible that hibernate does not inspect non-primitive members when doing a "findByExample" query?

Answer (score 1):

An old TODO in `org.hibernate.criterion.Example` class line `207` explains this issue:

```
//TODO: get all properties, not just the fetched ones!
Object[] propertyValues = meta.getPropertyValues( entity, getEntityMode(criteria, criteriaQuery) );
```

My workaround was compose a Criteria with the example object (following the original question):

```
Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(File.class);
Example ex = Example.create(exampleInstance);
crit.add(ex).add(Restrictions.eq("user", exampleInstance.getUser()));
return crit.list();
```